# Use the renewal equation to show that the renewal function of a Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

Use the renewal equation to show that the renewal function of a
Poisson process with rate $\lambda > 0$ is $m(t) = \lambda t$.

Answer (score 3):

The interrenewal distribution is exponential with rate $\lambda$, so $F(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$ and so the renewal equation gives us
\begin{align}
m(t) &= F(t) + F\star m(t)\\
&= 1-e^{-\lambda t} + \int_0^t m(t-s)\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= 1-e^{-\lambda t} + \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t m(x)e^{\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx
\end{align}
(with the substitution $x=t-s$). Multiplying by $e^{\lambda t}$ yields
$$e^{\lambda t}m(t) = e^{\lambda t} -1 +\lambda\int_0^t m(x)e^{\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx, $$
and after differentiating with respect to $t$ we have
$$\lambda e^{\lambda t}m(t) + e^{\lambda t}m'(t) = \lambda e^{\lambda t}+\lambda e^{\lambda t}m(t). $$ Therefore $m'(t)=\lambda$, and as $m(0)=0$, it follows that $m(t)=\lambda t$.