# Poisson Process Question: Expected time since last bus came?

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process, renewal-processes

You are waiting for the bus. You model the arrival process with a Poisson process N. of intensity λ with arrival times $(T_k)_{k≥0}$, $T_0$ = 0 and inter-arrival times $(X_k)_{k≥1}$. More precisely assume that we started our clock when the first bus of the day arrived (time zero.) Then the Poisson counting process counts the buses arriving within the time intervals (0, s], s ≥ 0. For instance $N_s = 0$ means that the previous bus was the initial one arriving at time 0.

You arrive at the bus stop at a fixed time t > 0. What is the expected value of the time passed since the last bus came? (if no buses besides the initial came, then t time has passed; if the bus arrives immediately after you, then 0 time has passed)

Comment: This is known as the "age" or "backward recurrence time" of a Poisson process (or more generally, a renewal process). See this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214248/age-and-residual-life-time-of-the-poisson-process

Comment: One way to do it is chop the size-$t$ interval into $k$ disjoint subintervals, each of size $t/k$, and an arrival occurs in each subinterval independently with prob $\lambda (t/k)$, no arrival with prob $1-\lambda(t/k)$ (an approx that is good for large $k$) and compute, then let $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_t = t - S_{N_t}$ be the age at time $t$, $F(t) = 1-e^{-\lambda t}$ the interarrival distribution, and $m(t) = \mathbb E[N_t]$ the renewal function. We know that $m(t) = \lambda t$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560604/use-the-renewal-equation-to-show-that-the-renewal-function-of-a-poisson-process) for a proof), and for $0<x\leqslant t$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(A_t\leqslant x) &= F(t) - \int_0^{t-x} (1-F(t-s))\ \mathsf dm(s)\\
&=1-e^{-\lambda t} - \int_0^{t-x}\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&=1-e^{-\lambda t} - (e^{-\lambda  x}-e^{-\lambda  t})\\
&=1 - e^{-\lambda x}.
\end{align}
Now, $\mathbb P(A_t\leqslant x)=1$ for $x>t$, so we have
$$
\mathbb E[A_t] = \int_0^t e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx = \frac1\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda t}).
$$

Comment: At a high level, what is your first main line (the one with the $\mathbb{P}[A_t \leq x]$ equality) saying? I understand that for $A_t$ to be less than or equal to $x$, it must be the case that there was some arrival in the interval [t-x, t], but how does that translate to the above? Specifically, why do you have F(t) outside of an integral in the first term and then inside of it in the second?

Comment: The formula is from *Stochastic models in queueing theory* by Jyotiprasad Medhi. He does not derive it in the book, but it results from conditioning on the time of the first arrival.